# applying scrollbars to pictureBox

Tags: c#, scrollbar, picturebox

I have looked at the examples on this and other sites to create this pictureBox. Yet I still can't figure out, why scrollbars are not shown. I guess I am missing a small but important detail :P. The Code below should be fully functional.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form2
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            //this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.panel1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.mPictureBoxPaint_Paint);   
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScroll = true;
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(391, 297);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Form2";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private void mPictureBoxPaint_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);
            blackPen.Width = 1.0F;
            blackPen.LineJoin = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineJoin.Bevel;

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) 
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen,
                        new Rectangle(i*20, j*20, 2, 2));
                }
            }


            blackPen.Dispose();
        }
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    }
}
```

Edit: Updated my Code(removed this.Controls.AddRange() and scrollbars). Now the pictureBox is fixed to panel, but panel does not recognize, if drawings are outside the borders. So still no scrollbars.

Edit2: Just realised that I dont even need a picturebox so I created a new example which is more easy to follow. If this.panel1.Dock is set, I see all points but no scrollbars, if it is not set I see scrollbars but not all Points. What I need is a Panel which automatically resizes according to the amount of points which should be shown, in a fixed windows size. So all Points are visible AND I have scrollbars.

Comment: The this.Controls.AddRange() call breaks it, it moves the pb from the panel to the form.  It now overlaps the panel, you won't see anything but the pb.  Don't do that.  And don't add scrollbars, Panel already knows how to display them.  Just make it smaller to see them.

Comment: @HansPassant I have updated my Code, according to your Comment, but still some troubles with scrollbars

Comment: Don't dock the pb.  Make it *larger* than the panel to get the scrollbars.

Comment: @HansPassant I get the scrollbars due to "make it larger" but it would not solve my problem. So I put a new example to clearify my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //just write number of Points you require on X-Axis of Y-Axis
        //This will also define how big the Panel gets
        int PointsX = 10;
        int PointsY = 5;
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            //this.panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1, 1);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size((PointsX*20), (PointsY*20));//Was 300,300
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.panel1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.mPictureBoxPaint_Paint);
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.AutoScroll = true;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 300);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Form2";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private void mPictureBoxPaint_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            Pen blackPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);
            blackPen.Width = 1.0F;
            blackPen.LineJoin = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineJoin.Bevel;

            for (int i = 0; i < PointsX; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < PointsY; j++) 
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(blackPen,
                        new Rectangle(i*20, j*20, 2, 2));
                }
            }


            blackPen.Dispose();
        }
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;


        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep exactly what I was looking for. I thought there were something predefined within c#, but this works also.

Comment: Good to hear,Good luck and happy Coding :-)